# Measurable and Lebesgue Integral function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Consider the function

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sin(x)}
$$
a) Is $f$ Lebesgue measurable?
b) is $f$ integrable on $\mathbb{R}$?

---

for a) I have if $A=\{y\in\mathbb{R} : \frac{1}{\sin(y)} = 0 \} \cup \{0\}$ is of measure 0 so the function is measurable.

for b) I am trying to solve using approximation lemma but it is not going well.

Comment: $A$ is of measure zero : how does this imply the function is measurable?(I know the answer, I want to know if you know)

Comment: All sets of measure 0 are measurable

Comment: Just because that set is measurable, doesn't mean $f$ is measurable. There is some other property of $f$ you are using ($f$ is something except at $A$), so what is that? (Also, $\{y \in \mathbb R : \frac 1{\sin y} = 0\}$ is empty  : you probably mean $\{y \in \mathbb R : \sin y = 0\}$ which makes sense)

Comment: im sorry i am a little confused

Comment: I'm using royden might pointing me in the right direction at the very least?

Comment: f is continuous? except at A

Comment: Right, that is what you should say : f is continuous except on a set of measure zero, so it is measurable.